# Filebrowser filename not working with get-content

Tags: powershell

I have following code on my form to get file name as selected by user and then perform action on the usernames inside that file. However, i am stuck as variable (created from filebrowser) passed to get-content wont work no matter what. Both codes (working and non-working as affixed)

```
   Working code:-
     
   $filepath = "c:\scripts\testusers.txt"
   $users = get-content -path $filpath
   . . . rest of code
   Code that wont work (and throws no error either)
   …
      $cmdFile.add_Click(
      {
       $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
       $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
       $Global:SelectedFile = $FileBrowser.FileName
       $filepath = $Global:SelectedFile ## this does not work
       ## $filepath = "c:\scripts\testusers.txt"   ## This works
       $users = get-content -path $filepath
         foreach ($u in $users)
          {
            ### control does not flow to this part of code
          }
       }
```

when i print value of $filepath in later part of code it prints correctly as c:\scripts\testusers.txt. Please let me know why this arrangement wont work.

Comment: Assuming `$FileBrowser` is a `Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`, you need to show the code where you use that.

Comment: complete code added for perusal please

Comment: $filepath = $SelectedFile?

Comment: What if you add `-encoding ascii` or `-encoding utf8` to your get-content

Comment: $filepath = $SelectedFile? (already tried) no luck. encoding didn't help either

Comment: When you say 'doesn't work', can you be more clear? How does it not work? It works fine when I try it.

Comment: You probably want to include an addtional check to see if the user actually selected a file in the OpenFileDialog (instead of cancel it) but that's for later.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven: When I set $filepath to C:\scripts\testusers.txt then get-content -path $filepaths reads the file successfully. when I set $filepath to $Global:SelectedFile and then user get-content -path $filepath, code does not read file and outputs nothing at all

Comment: [1] You need to compare `$filepath` to the hardcoded path that works. `Write-Host ($filepath -eq 'c:\scripts\testusers.txt')`. I'll bet they are not the same. [2] you will get a problem with that global SelectedFile variable if you never remove the $FileBrowser object from memory when finished with it.. After the dialog has been shown, and IF the user indeed selected a file, store that `$FileBrowser.FileName` in a variable and perform `$FileBrowser.Dispose()`

Comment: [3] $FileBrowser has properties `Multiselect` (in your case should be set to `$false`) and `CheckFileExists` (in your case i'd suggest setting that to `$true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, by never clearing the $FileBrowser dialog object from memory, you will eventually run into problems.
Also - although I cannot see the reason for storing the selected file in a global variable by looking at your question - you need to clear that global variable each time you enter the click event to prevent keeping stale information in there.

Try

```
$cmdFile.Add_Click({
    # start by clearing the $Global:SelectedFile variable
    $Global:SelectedFile = $null

    $FileBrowser = New-Object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $FileBrowser.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt;*.csv|All Files|*.*"
    $FileBrowser.Multiselect = $false
    $FileBrowser.CheckFileExists = $true
    $null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

    # get the selected filename if any
    $filePath = $FileBrowser.Filename
    # clean up the dialog object from memory
    $FileBrowser.Dispose()

    # check if you received a file name
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($filePath)) {
        # you can set your global variable here if you must
        $Global:SelectedFile = $filePath
        Get-Content -Path $filepath | ForEach-Object {
            # perform an action on each username in the file
            # each line of the file is represented by the $_ automatic variable
        }
    }
})
```

P.S. by setting the `Multiselect` property to `$false` you tell the dialog to accept and return only one file in its `$FileBrowser.Filename` property. If this is set to `$true`, the selected file(s) are returned via `$FileBrowser.Filenames` (note the 's', plural)

Comment: yes sir. i was using global variable in like 20 plus click events and it was polluted. thanks every one. i was away as i was quaranteened for being COVID suspect. but m negative so u r all safe ;)

Comment: @jaykio77 Thanks for letting us know. Glad you're safe too ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
  
 #------------- Form Code ------- 
  $cmdFile.Add_Click({
  
  #Note: I like to define the $FileBrowser outside of click event
  #      so it can be reused without reinitializing
  
    $FileBrowser.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt;*.csv|All Files|*.*"
    If ($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq "Cancel") {
      $filepath = ""
    }
    Else {
      $filepath = $FileBrowser.Filename
      $FileBrowser.FileName = $Null
      $FileBrowser.Filter = ""
      
#Are you really using SelectedFile as a Global, multiple scripts?
#or just in this script which would then be $Script vs $Global. 
# I'd use this to see if the problem is here or later where the
#Global is used.
      $Global:SelectedFile = "$filePath" 
      $users = get-content -path "$filepath"
      foreach ($u in $users) {
            ### control does not flow to this part of code
      }
      
    }
   })

#---------- Main Code --------------

$FileBrowser   = New-Object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
```

HTH

Comment: I use global as it will be used in multiple click events. Problem isn't with global:SelectedFile variable as it outputs correct value when I use write-host $filepath. The mystery is this: When I set $filepath to C:\scripts\testusers.txt then get-content -path $filepaths reads the file successfully. when I set $filepath to $Global:SelectedFile and then use get-content -path $filepath, code does not read file and outputs nothing at all